# Is there a Linux and Mac equivalent of Launch4j that's free?

Tags: linux, java, macos

I think this software is great but I can't seem to find anything that does the same thing for Mac or Linux builds. Here's the software if you aren't familiar with it.

[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

The reason why I want to wrap them is because a user might not have Java installed rendering the jar file useless and in that scenario I'd like it to prompt them to install Java.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. // So: What should the program do (and what not)?